# How to get unsigned float in java

Tags: java

I have a [sample](https://github.com/elect86/jogl-samples/blob/master/jogl-samples/src/tests/gl_420/Gl_420_image_load.java#L312) where I need to put float values (as `imageSize.x` and `imageSize.x`) as unsigned floats inside a bytebuffer, because this is how the [fragment shader](https://github.com/elect86/jogl-samples/blob/master/jogl-samples/src/data/gl_420/image-load.frag#L18) expects them to be.

Since for this specific sample, I needed to upload twice an unsigned `256.0f`, that in binary is `1 0000 0000`, I tried to upload (byte) `0100` (small endian + 2 zero bytes for padding) twice, and it worked flawless.

But I would like to have a more elegant and general case to avoid passing throught byte....Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[try this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#intBitsToFloat%28int%29)

```
Float.intBitsToFloat(int bits)
```

Comment: `pointer.putFloat(Float.intBitsToFloat((int) imageSize.x));` works! Thanks man, could you just expand it a little? Ps: I can accept it in 3...crap

Comment: there is full description: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#intBitsToFloat%28int%29